# Swift 4.1 couldn't not convert String to local Date, always return UTC Date

Tags: swift, date, localtime

I want to transfer a date string to Date.

```
let a = DateFormatter()
a.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
guard let datea = a.date(from: "2018-06-21 00:00:00") else {
        fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
}
print("ans", datea)
```

But it  always print "ans 2018-06-20 16:00:00 +0000" 
Why it could not print the original string date "2018-06-21 00:00:00"?
What wrong with my code ?

Comment: Because `print` displays dates always in UTC by definition. if you need local time use another date formatter or set the time zone of the input formatter to UTC

Comment: add  `a.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")` //Current time zone

Answer (score 1):

A Date is not a string. A Date is a moment in time. It has no clock. It has no time zones. It has no calendar. It is just an instant in time, independent of location or localization.

As a debugging convenience, a Date can be easily converted to a string in a pre-defined format using its `.description` (which is what `print` calls). As with all `.description` methods, you should never use this string for anything but debugging (or possibly logging). There is no promise about what format this string is in.

If you need some specific string representation, then you should use the `DateFormatter`:

```
print("ans", a.string(from: datea))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `timeZone` to get the time according to that provided timeZone so to convert UTC time to local time your code should be look like that.

```
    let a = DateFormatter()
    a.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    a.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let dt = a.date(from: "2018-06-21 00:00:00")
    a.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    a.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //change the dateFormat according to your need
    let dateString = a.string(from: dt!)

    print("now the dateString is \(dateString)")

   //printed result (now the dateString is 2018-06-21 05:30:00 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rob Napier says in his answer, a `Date` object does not have a time zone. It represents a moment in time anywhere on the planet.

If you want to display a Date as a month, day, year, and time, you need to specify a particular time zone.

If you just print a date, like `print(Date())`, you get the default `description` property of the date object, which shows the date expressed in UTC. That's probably not what you want.

I defined an extension to Date that lets me see dates expressed in the user's current locale and time zone:

```
extension Date {
    func localString(dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium) -> String {
        return DateFormatter.localizedString(from: self, dateStyle: dateStyle, timeStyle: timeStyle)
    }
    func timeString(timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium) -> String {
        return localString(dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: timeStyle)
    }
}
```

If you add that extension to your project you can use it like this:

```
print(print("ans", datea.localString())
```

And you'll see your Date in the device's current time zone. It's very useful for debugging.